# Are results from CFD analysis enough to write and publish a paper?

Tags: research-process, thesis, research-undergraduate

**Some intro :** 

I am a student of BTech Aeronautical Engineering from India. 
And I am going to publish something in a scientific journal.

**Dilemma :**

My research is about CFD (Computational Fluid Dynamics) and has been, mainly, taken into account by simulation, as developing a real model will be infeasible for me, in view of financial issues.

So, is it possible to publish the results only, with the data of the CFD analysis result backing up my thesis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Possibly Yes

If you are using an [already validated CFD code](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/wind/valid/tutorial/overview.html), then any unique or interesting results that you find would be candidate material for an article.

If you are writing your own CFD code, then you must validate/verify it before you publish your code's results.

[In code validation,]

> The overall objective is to demonstrate the accuracy of CFD codes so
>   that they may be used with confidence for aerodynamic simulation and
>   that the results be considered credible for decision making in design.
>   ...
>   Credibility is obtained by
>   demonstrating acceptable levels of uncertainty and error. A discussion
>   of the uncertainties and errors in CFD simulations is provided on the
>   page entitled Uncertainty and Error in CFD Simulations. The levels of
>   uncertainties and errors are determined through verification
>   assessment and validation assessment.

There are several methods of validation but the two widely accepted methods are:

1. Simulate a configuration that you can test, then test that
   configuration.  If your code's results matches the test results, that's
   generally considered a good validation.
2. Simulate a configuration that you can model with an already
   validated CFD code.  If their results agree, that's also considered
   a good validation.

Of course you still need to perform a grid sizing analysis and other tests to ensure/prove you're using your code correctly.

Comment: If you have a new CFD code, then most journals would accept it only if it is better in some way than existing code. Is it faster, more accurate, or at least easier to apply for particular types of cases than existing options?

Answer (score 1):

In principle yes! There are numerous publications that merely use commercial CFD packages. What makes your commercial CFD solver simulations publishable?

- **Validation** of your results (completely or partially) by some other scholar's experimental results.
- A hot topic that **has not been touched by CFD community before**. A colleague of mine just published his pure commercial CFD results in a very prestigious journal.
- Your **adviser reputation** and network. Some Professors are well known in their own field. Naturally, any publications coming with their name on it bears a message: Most probably the results make sense and contribute to the field.
- Never underestimate the power of a good CFD simulation. So many scientist are not aware of what is going on in industry. There are **R&D people in industry** who are looking for similar CFD simulations and respect its practical value.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, simulation results in CFD can be published. When evaluating a paper showing model results, I consider:

- What does it tell us that is new? Is it giving new insight into the system being modelled, and is this insight generalisable to a category of simular systems? Is it giving us new insight into how a process works? Or large-scale emergent patterns from detailed processes? Is it telling us more about the accuracy and limitations of the model? Or is it presenting a new approach to modelling or model evaluation?
- Will the results be useful to other people interested in other systems?
- How effectively has the model been evaluated and assessed?